# Android setdrawable from another class

Tags: android, xml, getresource

Here's my code. I am trying to set background of a linear layout. But this xml (rowback) is not my main activity content, so gives errors. how can I set some XML from the class which doesn't have that XML in its content?

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_quick_search_products);
...
rowb = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.rowback);
...
final Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.denemebut3);
d.setAlpha(100);
rowb.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
```

Logcat:

```
03-30 02:52:50.822: D/AndroidRuntime(14677): Shutting down VM
03-30 02:52:50.822: W/dalvikvm(14677): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40c841f8)
03-30 02:52:50.822: E/AndroidRuntime(14677): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-30 02:52:50.822: E/AndroidRuntime(14677): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.vitrinn/com.vitrinn.QuickSearchProducts}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-30 02:52:50.822: E/AndroidRuntime(14677):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1968)
03-30 02:52:50.822: E/AndroidRuntime(14677):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1993)
03-30 02:52:50.822: E/AndroidRuntime(14677):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:127)
03-30 02:52:50.822: E/AndroidRuntime(14677):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1159)
03-30 02:52:50.822: E/AndroidRuntime(14677):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-30 02:52:50.822: E/AndroidRuntime(14677):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
03-30 02:52:50.822: E/AndroidRuntime(14677):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4507)
03-30 02:52:50.822: E/AndroidRuntime(14677):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-30 02:52:50.822: E/AndroidRuntime(14677):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
03-30 02:52:50.822: E/AndroidRuntime(14677):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:978)
03-30 02:52:50.822: E/AndroidRuntime(14677):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:745)
03-30 02:52:50.822: E/AndroidRuntime(14677):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-30 02:52:50.822: E/AndroidRuntime(14677): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-30 02:52:50.822: E/AndroidRuntime(14677):    at com.vitrinn.QuickSearchProducts.onCreate(QuickSearchProducts.java:69)
03-30 02:52:50.822: E/AndroidRuntime(14677):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4469)
03-30 02:52:50.822: E/AndroidRuntime(14677):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1052)
03-30 02:52:50.822: E/AndroidRuntime(14677):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1932)
03-30 02:52:50.822: E/AndroidRuntime(14677):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Your problem is not because you are calling `setBackgroundDrawable()` on a View.  The code you have is perfectly fine, but you have a reference wrong somewhere so an object is null (hence, `NullPointerException`).  Find line 69 in onCreate() and that will tell you the null object that you need to correct.

Comment: in the line 69 there is this line:

rowb.setBackgroundDrawable(d);

Comment: Are you sure that rowb is not null?

Comment: no, it is not null. But row.xml is not the content of my view. so how can I change something inside row.xml from this class?

Answer (score 0):

If ***R.id.rowback*** doesn't belong to your main activity xml resource, then you should inflate that resource manually using:

```java
LinearLayout rowb = (LinearLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(XML file that contains R.id.rowback, null);
```

then you can safely do

> rowb.setBackgroundDrawable(d);

As an extra, if you have nested elements in *rowback* then you can invoke:

```
rowb.findViewById(R.id.Something) safely.
```

Or if your class is not exteding from any Activity, you can always receive a Context object in its constructor, and then use

```java
LayoutInflater.from(context)
```

to get a LayoutInflater object so you can inflate any XML resource you need that is not actually in your main content.

Hope this clarifies...

Comment: Do you mean this??

View vieww = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.id.rowback, null);
     rowb = (LinearLayout)vieww.findViewById(R.id.rowback);
     final Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.denemebut);
     d.setAlpha(100);
     rowb.setBackgroundDrawable(d);

Comment: That doesn't work. It gives error on line: View vieww = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.id.rowback, null);

Comment: Nope you stated R.id.rowback is a LinearLayout, since it doesn't belong to you main XML content you should inflate ther XML resource containing it... my apologies i din't notice i put R.id.rowback as to be infalted i really meant to inflate resource containing it... i edited post so you can grasp it